# OAuth 2,0 Token End Points

Tags: oauth

What is the difference between the following token generation end points.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

/Amaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between the following token generation end
>   points.
>
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/token
>
> https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token

Both `/oauth2/token` and `/oauth2/v2.0/token` produce the access token. But, there are several differences when using them:

1. Both `/oauth2/token` and `/oauth2/v2.0/token` **have different parameters request**. Take a look at **resource** and **scope**.

   `/oauth2/token` parameters request: grant_type, client_id, client_secret, assertion, **resource,** requested_token_use. (https://dzone.com/articles/getting-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-using-oau-1)

   `/oauth2/v2.0/token` parameters request: grant_type, client_id, client_secret, assertion, **scope,** requested_token_use. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)
2. `/oauth2/v2.0/token` is **newer endpoint version**. You can notice from `v2.0`. It is common for a big company like Microsoft to upgrade their technology to newer version. The newer version could have better support, security, etc. Normally, they will also keep the old endpoint version to support the technology who implemented using old endpoint. It is also recommended to use the latest version of `endpoint` when possible.

I hope this answers your question.